# KendoGrid refresh

Tags: kendo-grid, refresh, datasource

I'm using KendoGrid to display some data fetched from my service.

The user selects some parameters (company and date) and cliks on a load button.

The user selects a month on a datePicker and the server will return data from that date plus 11 months.

I only display the grid after the user click on the load button.

**Load function:**

```
function loadGrid(e) {

    var companyIds = [1, 3, 7]; // user select it

    var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
    var rowHeaders = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K"];

    var _dataSource = function () {

        var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: URL,
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        companyIds: companyIds,
                        date: kendo.toString(picker.value(), "yyyy-MM-dd") // user select it
                    }
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: function (data) {

                    // function to handle data returned from server

                    var dataArray = [];
                    var index = 0;
                    for (var key in data[0]) {
                        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(data[0], key)) {
                            var property = key;
                            if (property == "date") {
                                continue;
                            }
                            key = {};
                            key["X"] = rowHeaders[index];
                            index++;
                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                var date = data[i].date;
                                var dateSplit = date.split("-");
                                var year = dateSplit[0];
                                var month = months[dateSplit[1] - 1];
                                var header = month + "_" + year;
                                key[header] = data[i][property];
                            }
                            dataArray.push(key);
                        }
                    }
                    return dataArray;
                }
            }
        });
        return dataSource;
    };

    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        scrollable: false,
        editable: false,
        dataSource: _dataSource()
    });
}
```

When I click on the load button for the first time, the datasource is loaded and the grid is displayed correctly.

But, for instance, if I change the date on the datePicker and click on the load button again, the datasource is loaded with the correct data (new records for other months), but the grid is not refreshed.

If the first time I select the month `Jan/2015`, it loads and displays from `Jan/2015` until `Dec/2015`, which is correct.

But if than I select the month `Feb/2015`, the datasource loads from `Feb/2015` until `Jan/2016` (correct), but the grid display the columns from `Jan/2015` until `Dec/2015`, which is wrong. In this case, the column `Jan/2015` is shown empty and the column `Jan/2016` is not displayed.

Can someone point me to the right direction?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use a function for your dataSource -> transport -> read -> data:

```js
data: function() {
    return {
               companyIds: companyIds,
               date: kendo.toString(picker.value(), "yyyy-MM-dd") // user select it
           };
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is how I would do it:

```js
function loadGrid(e) {
    $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.fetch();
}

function getData() {
    var companyIds = ...
    var picker = ...
    return {
        companyIds: companyIds,
        date: kendo.toString(picker.value(), "yyyy-MM-dd") // user select it
    };
}

var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: URL,
            dataType: "json",
            data: getData
        }
    },
    schema: {
        data: function (data) {

            // function to handle data returned from server

            var dataArray = [];
            var index = 0;
            for (var key in data[0]) {
                if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(data[0], key)) {
                    var property = key;
                    if (property == "date") {
                        continue;
                    }
                    key = {};
                    key["X"] = rowHeaders[index];
                    index++;
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        var date = data[i].date;
                        var dateSplit = date.split("-");
                        var year = dateSplit[0];
                        var month = months[dateSplit[1] - 1];
                        var header = month + "_" + year;
                        key[header] = data[i][property];
                    }
                    dataArray.push(key);
                }
            }
            return dataArray;
        }
    }
});

$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    scrollable: false,
    editable: false,
    dataSource: dataSource
});
```

Comment: Make sure the data function uses the newly selected values, not some variables from the closure. I would use a simple dataSource, with `data: someFunction` where `someFunction` is a global function, and call `grid.dataSource.fetch()` to update the grid.

Comment: You are right, the way you did it is better. I change my code, but still does not work. When I click on load button, loads the data, but when I change the parameters and click again, nothing happens. So I change `fetch` to `read`, set the `autoBind` to `false` on the `grid` configuration and now it loads the second time. But the same problem occurs. The data loads, but the grid does not refresh.

Comment: I'm out of ideas. Maybe you should include a fiddle, so one might spot the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up destroying and recreating the grid when the user clicks on `load button`.

```
$("#loadButton").kendoButton({
    click: loadGrid
});

var loaded = false;
function loadGrid(e) {

    if (value) {

        if (loaded) {
            var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
            grid.wrapper.empty();
            grid.destroy();
        }

        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            scrollable: false,
            editable: false,
            autoBind: false,
            dataSource: _dataSource()
        });

        $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
        loaded = true;
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("aaaa");
    }
}
```